# How to assign string data to viewmodel in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my code

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
   public list<student> StudentId{get;set;}
}

public calss student
{
  public List<string> Marks {get;set;}
  public string Id{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

i have string data like

```
[{"id":"101","name":"abc","marks":[["67","34"]]},{"id":"102","name":"xyz","marks":[["98"],["85]]}]
```

In the above student view model contains list class student. i have number of student details. how to assign the above string data to view model in mvc controller.

Comment: Not clear what you trying to do. Are you posting this to a controller method using ajax?

Comment: no iam passing string data from angularjs to mvc controller

Comment: Then edit you question to show what you are doing (and show the controller method signature)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your string data into C# object using any json parser e.g. [newton soft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) and convert it into C# object.

```
var student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<student>>(strInput);
```

or You can also use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` and code will be as follows

```
var students= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<student>>(strInput);
```

Comment: what is exception, have you added newtonsoft js? or you can use mvc deseralizer.

Comment: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path '[0].alternateIds[0]', line 1, position 69.